# Cookie seems to never exist

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am facing a weird issue regarding cookies: I am trying to set up a cookie with the user id the first time the user logs into the application, and next time, if the cookie exists, not require the user authentication again.

For this I am using the code below:

- to set the cookie:

  ```
  HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("UserCookie");
  userCookie.Value = UserId.ToString();
  userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
  ```
- to get the cookie:

  ```
  HttpCookie UserCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserCookie"];
  if (UserCookie != null)
  {
        // redirect the user to another screen inside the application
  }
  ```

The weird thing is that my cookie seems not to exist and the user is prompted with the log in screen all the time. When I try to use debugging, it appears to me that the cookie is not null, but it's got an empty string value. What can I do about this?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the type of UserId? Is it an integer?

Comment: Yes, it has an integer value.

Comment: Try adding additional hours than just one. Instead of adding a single hour to the time, try adding 7 days. It might be the browser interpreting the time (with UTC or something) wrong.

Comment: Quick security note: I don't know your full implementation or if you've considered this, but if your user ids are sequential and stored in the cookie in plain text, anyone could craft a cookie to log in as whoever they wanted without a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to GET the cookie in the same code that SETS the cookie? If so, the cookie won't exist. Cookie gets SET on the users browser when the page has been delivered.

Also, can you confirm `UserID.ToString()` isn't actually an empty string..?

To test properly, set the cookie on page A, then redirect to page B and GET the cookie here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can confirm that UserID.ToString() is not the empty string, I have also tried setting this cookie in the login page and getting it in another page, it works perfectly. As for the get and set part, in the login page I first check if the cookie is set and if not set, I try to set it.

Comment: I'm really confused... you say that you set it in login and can get it on another page perfectly? Are you saying that the next time you visit the login page the cookie isn't present?

Comment: I finally managed to get it right: seems it was because my cookie code was executed only when some variables were not null and since they were null my cookie wasn't set right. Thanks for your suggestion of trying to get the cookie value in another page, it helped me figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's all working. By the way, not sure if you're aware, though when it comes time to remove a cookie the Cookies.Delete(yourCookie) doesn't actually delete it from the browser - you need to set the expire date to a date in the past, such as myCookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(-1) - then set the cookie. It will kill it on the browser.